# Automating data extraction and loading to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, data-extraction, google-cloud-scheduler

I am learning how to pull data from GraphQL API and load it to BigQuery table on daily basis. I am new to GCP and trying to understand the set-up required to establish a secure data-pipeline. To automate the process of regular data extraction and loading, I am following the steps below,

- I am first creating a Cloud Function using BigQuery Python client library with pandas and pyarrow. I am loading the data to BigQuery using the method shown in this - Using BigQuery with Pandas — google-cloud-bigquery documentation (googleapis.dev).
- As the Trigger type, I have chosen Cloud Pub/Sub. Can I please know if that is a good choice (secure and efficient) for data extraction or should I go with HTTP which requires authentication or with any other Trigger type for my use case.
- After which, among the settings, I am setting up only Runtime (is there any other settings that I need to configure?)
- Once, the above Cloud Function is set-up, I am creating a Cloud Scheduler to call the Cloud Function created above once everyday at midnight. Under ‘Configure the execution’ I am selecting Target type as Cloud Pub/Sub and selecting the topic.
  I do not understand the need for ‘Message body’ after selecting the Cloud Pub/Sub topic to set up Cloud Scheduler for data extraction use case, however, it is an essential field in the settings. I am using a generic message (something like ‘hello world’). Could anyone please correct me if it has any significance, again for my use case and how best to set it?

If anyone of you could please review this method to extract and load data to BQ and please let me know if it is an efficient and secure pipeline, that will be very helpful.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all slow down a little :D.
You are mixing up two functionalities.

Cloud function can be triggered either via HTTP request or via Pubsub.
When you use cloud scheduler with pubsub topic, the body field there allows you to enter custom data you want to add. This will be sent to the pubsub by cloud scheduler and when the cloud function is triggered via pubsub, it will get the message set by the cloud scheduler. You can use this to trigger different modules of you code based on input you get. AGain its use case specific.

In your case, either of the technique will work. HTTP is easy because you just have to setup the cloud function with appropriate service account, h/w configs. Once deployed, use the trigger url to setup cloud scheduler. Whereas for pubsub there is an additional component in between.

Please read the cloud function document properly. It contains all details on when to use which trigger.

Hope this answers.